# Objective C, xpath query not working

Tags: objective-c, xpath, hpple

I have next html structure

```
<div class="item column-1">
  <h2>
    <a href="/news/1172-zimnee-21-12-2014">
      some text
    </a>
  </h2>

</div>
```

I want to get content of a tag, I'm using this code

```
NSURL *newURL = [NSURL URLWithString:@"http://mfc.mk.ua/news"];
NSData *newsData = [NSData dataWithContentsOfURL: newURL];

TFHpple *newsParser = [TFHpple hppleWithHTMLData: newsData];

NSString *newsXpathQueryString = @"//div[@class='item column-1']/h2/a";
NSArray *newsNodes = [newsParser searchWithXPathQuery: newsXpathQueryString];

NSMutableArray *newNews = [[NSMutableArray alloc] initWithCapacity: 0];

for (TFHppleElement *element in newsNodes)
{
    News *news = [[News alloc] init];

    [newNews addObject: news];

    news.title = [[element firstChild] content];

    _objects = newNews;
}
```

But it returning no results. If I do this:

```
news.title = [element objectForKey:@"href"];
```

then I'm getting results. What I doing wrong? Please help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want "some text" in your example, rather than `[[element firstChild] content]`, you should use simply `[element content]`. If your example is representative, but you might want to trim white space and new lines, too. Thus:

```
news.title = [[element content] stringByTrimmingCharactersInSet:[NSCharacterSet whitespaceAndNewlineCharacterSet]];
```

Comment: news.title = [[element content] stringByTrimmingCharactersInSet:[NSCharacterSet whitespaceAndNewlineCharacterSet]];
This works perfectly, and [element content] dont work.
Thank you a lot!